# Looking for a way to create compressed png files in lua/luajit

Tags: lua, png, libpng, luajit

I'm writing a mod for a game that uses lua/luajit as a scripting language and I would like to create a png file dynamically using lua. I've been googling for a png library/module but could only find ones that merely read pngs (like https://github.com/Didericis/png-lua or https://luapower.com/libpng), or create uncompressed pngs: https://github.com/wyozi/lua-pngencoder

On my search I have stumbled upon libpng and thought, maybe I could simply load that dll using ffi and use the functions that way. But the problem is that is waaaay too complicated for me, since I'm not familiar with C and furthermore libpng seems to be a huuuuuge complicated library.

So, is there any simple way (module/library) that I missed and didn't find on google?
I just need very simple functionality, create a png, set the pixels, save it as a compressed png file.

Comment: What format is the image data that you want to make a PNG out of? Do you just have tables full of RGB values?

Comment: I want to create a small empty image (128x128 max), then iterate over every pixel and set their (A)RGB values individually. But of course I could also write the values into a table instead and then pass it on to a function that makes a PNG out of it.

Comment: You could produce a [PPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#PPM_example) image with no library (it's a super-simple format), then call `pnmtopng` from the netpbm package, or `convert` from the ImageMagick package. That's not the most efficient approach, but I think it's the simplest.

Comment: Also, where do you want the output PNG to end up? Saved to a file, or a string of its contents?

Comment: Saved to a file. Your idea of creating one format and then simply converting it to PNG opens up new possibilites, I like it.

Comment: The LuaJIT FFI isn't that complicated. I'll try to write up an answer that uses it.

Comment: Why don't you try to make that lua specific library work for you? If you post the code which you tried (make it a [mcve] please), it could be scrutinized by the Lua experts.

Comment: Does using `wb` instead of `w` make it produce a valid PNG?

Comment: Actually, when I run the code you posted, I get a solid red square. What program is telling you that it's invalid?

Comment: IrfanView and the VSCode image preview. Changing it to `wb` worked, thanks! Might be good enough for me already, but getting compressed PNG would be really nice.

Comment: Okay, let me see how difficult libpng will be...

Comment: Looks like someone already did libpng bindings: https://github.com/luapower/libpng Do they work for you?

Comment: No I tried but can't get it to work. cannot load module 'png': The specified module could not be found. I guess that is the libpng.dll? But when I paste that in the folder, rename it to png.dll and try to load it I get:

luajit: .\libpng.lua:12: cannot load module 'png': %1 is not a valid Win32 application.